# Start a spring boot service with colored console logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, systemd, syslog, rsyslog

I have a Spring Boot app running as a systemd service.

When I start it (with `sudo service myapp start` or `sudo systemctl start myapp`), I'd like to see console logs with colors like I do in Eclipse or using `java -jar myapp.jar`

I think the starting colored logs are useful to see a WARN or ERROR without doing additional operations like greps.

I know I can do : `sudo service myapp start; journalctl -f -u myapp`, but it will show double timestamp and no colors.

I've tried to setup myapp.service with these parameters :

```
StandardOutput=syslog+console
StandardErr=syslog+console
```

But it looks like the "console" part is ignored,or I don't understand what "console" means in this context, do I need to be logged as root to see this console ?

**Update** :
The best approach I could have is to display the content of /dev/vcs but there is no color, no new line, and it's not even displaying continuously when I do "`tail -f`".

I guess the best solution is to have a special pattern for console logs to remove the duplicate timestamp per line, and just accept the white and black output.

Comment: Have u tried spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS in your application.properties?

Comment: On console, there is just no text, it's not about colors. On file, there is no color, but it's normal, there will never be.